# How to implement multiple conditions for single table column in PhalconPHP

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon, phalcon-orm

What would be the right syntax to find the sum of money saved in plans where the `status` is either `abanadoned` or `completed`:

```
$total = self::sum([
    'column' => 'amount_saved_so_far',
    'conditions' => 'status = "completed" AND user_id = :user_id:',
    //find plans with a status of abandoned as well
    'bind' => ['user_id' => $userId]
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do and it's perfectly fine solution:

```
$total = self::sum([
    'column' => 'amount_saved_so_far',
    'conditions' => '(status = "completed" OR status = "abanadoned") 
                     AND user_id = :user_id:',
    'bind' => ['user_id' => $userId]
]);
```

Or another option would be to use array binding:

```
$total = self::sum([
    'column' => 'amount_saved_so_far',
    'conditions' => 'status IN ({vars:array}) AND user_id = :user_id:',
    'bind' => [
        'vars' => ['completed', 'abanadoned'],
        'user_id' => $userId
    ]
]);
```

Second option is more elegant and more practical in case you have more values for the IN clause.

Comment: You've forgot the bind part in your first snippet

Comment: Stripped the example on purpose to show only important parts.

Comment: As it's an answer for beginner phalconist question I'd post full code. It's still quite short. But it's just my opinion. Your answer - your rules

Comment: You have convinced me! :)